# Facebook Connect triggers isCancelled event even when pressed OK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am using `React-native` to build a small app (which I don't think is relevant).

The app finally goes to Facebook to request authorisation.

But when I click ok, I am sent to a `isCancelled` callback.

Here is the "FacebookLoginManager.m":

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "FacebookLoginManager.h"
#import "FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h"
#import "FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h"

@implementation FacebookLoginManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(newSession:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
  FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
  [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
      callback(@[@"Error", [NSNull null]]);
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
      callback(@[@"Canceled", [NSNull null]]); // I GET HERE AFTER CLICKING OK!
    } else {
      FBSDKAccessToken *token = result.token;
      NSString *tokenString = token.tokenString;
      NSString *userId = token.userID;
      NSDictionary *credentials = @{ @"token" : tokenString, @"userId" : userId };
      callback(@[[NSNull null], credentials]);
    }
  }];
};

@end
```

[image: Auth from facebook]

Answer (score 1):

turns out my `AppDelegate.m` was misconfigured:
here it is after the fix,

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h"
#import "RCTRootView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"TourChampIOs"
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                     annotation:annotation];
}

@end
```

hope this helps others.